# A simple question about sequence convergente

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have a simple question that I find true but I'm not able to justify it at least so it convinces me ... Suppose we have $\left(u_n\right)$ such that you know the sequence $\left(u_n+u_{n-2}\right)$ [for example] converges, let's say towards $\ell$. Is it possible to prove or disprove that $\left(u_n\right)$ converges and $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty}u_n = \frac{\ell}{2}$ ?

Comment: Hi :) unfortunately, it's false. Let $u_{2n}=u_{2n-1}=(-1) ^n$, then $u_{n-2}+u_n$ is constant.

Comment: There are lots of 'smoothing' techniques that turn non convergent sequences into convergent ones (cf. Cesàro summation, for example).